# Bijection between $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\dots$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Is there a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\dots$ for countably infinitely many $\mathbb{Z}$'s and $\mathbb{R}$? That is, is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\dots$, repeated countably infinitely many times, uncountable?

Comment: The question after "that is" is not equivalent to the question in the first sentence; not all uncountable sets have the cardinality of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: What other sets do you know to be uncountable?  What other sets do you know to be "bijectable" with $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 10):

First note that as joriki commented there are many uncountable sets which are not of the same size as the real numbers. There *might* be uncountable sets which are strictly smaller than the real numbers.

To both your questions, however, the answer is yes. Note that:

$$\mathbb{Z\times Z\times Z\times\dots = Z^N}\\\mathbb{R\times R\times R\times\dots = R^N}$$

Now we have this: $$|\mathbb R|=2^{|\mathbb N|}\leq|\mathbb Z|^{|\mathbb N|}\leq|\mathbb R|^{|\mathbb N|}=2^{|\mathbb{N\times N}|}=2^{|\mathbb N|}=|\mathbb R|$$

Comment: Can we consider any other countable set instead of $\mathbb Z$? Is the problem remained valid? Thanks Asaf. I am a  
disciple of you here.

Comment: Obviously we can. Any set below the cardinality of $\mathbb R$, as a matter of fact.